# Declaring variable in IF statement

Tags: powershell

Why won't this work?

```
if (([datetime] $a = Date),$a.DayOfWeek -ne 'Wednesday'){
    Write-Host 1
    Exit
}ElseIf ($a.hour -ne 9){
    Write-Host 2
    Exit
}

Do stuff...
```

but this will

```
if (($connected = Test-Connection 1.1.1.1 -Quiet), $connected -eq $false){
    Start-Process msg -ArgumentList "$env:USERNAME Not Connected..."
    Exit
}

Do stuff..
```

In the first example my script always exits unless I move `[datetime] $a = date` outside if statement. However, the second example works without issue.

Also, if insert `$a` in the first if statement it returns the correct `datetime`.

Comment: `if ($([datetime] $a = Date;$a.DayOfWeek -ne 'Wednesday')){`

Comment: @PetSerAl works like a charm.

Comment: `get-help about_Operator_Precedence`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `,` inside an if statement, as it results in the creation of a 2-item array - an object that `if()` will always evaluate to `$true`.

The reason for this, is that when you enclose an assignment operation in plaint parentheses (that is: `()`, not `$()` which a the subexpression operator), the right-hand side of the assignment is itself returned:

```
PS C:\> $null = 123 # the operation itself doesn't generate output
PS C:\> ($null = 123) # but we can force it to do so
123
```

So when you do something like:

```
($a = Get-Date),$a -eq (Get-Date)
```

you're really producing the following expression: `@($a,$a) -eq (Get-Date)`

---

You can do it like this instead:

```
if(([datetime]$a = Date).DayOfWeek -ne 'Wednesday'){
    # It's not wednesday
}
```

and

```
if (($connected = Test-Connection 1.1.1.1 -Quiet) -eq $false){
    # No response
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ultimately used the following code:

```
if ($([datetime] $a = Date; $a.DayOfWeek -ne 'Wednesday') -eq $true){
    Write-Host 1
    Exit
}ElseIf ($a.hour -ne 9){
    Write-Host 2
    Exit
}

Do stuff..
```

and

```
if ($($connected = Test-Connection 1.1.1.1 -Quiet; $connected) -eq $false){
    Write-Host 3
    Exit
}

Do stuff..
```